# tikzpicture x ticks are aligned on the side

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, axis

I want my x-ticks to be aligned below the x-axes. But as it is right now,
the ticks are overlapping with the x axes. All examples I've found online don't
specifiy the position of the x labels but they are correctly aligned.

I also would like to know, how I can put the label of the y axes ( <i(t)> ) on top
of the y axes.

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code so far:

```
\begin{center}
            \resizebox{10cm}{!}{
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[
                grid=major,
                xtick align = center,
                xlabel={$t$},
                ylabel={$<i(t)>$},
                xmin=0,
                xmax=3,
                xtick={1,2,3},
                ymin=0,
                ymax=20,
                ytick={0,5,10,15,20}
                ]
                \addplot[thick,samples=400] {((1-2)*(x/1-1))^(1/(1-2))};
                \node at (axis cs:0.6,18) {$\kappa = 2$};
                \addplot[thick,samples=400] {((1-0.5)*(x/1+2))^(1/(1-0.5))};
                \node at (axis cs:2.6,7) {$\kappa = 0.5$};
                \addplot[thick,samples=400] {(exp(x/1+0))};
                \node at (axis cs:2.6,18) {$\kappa = 1$};
                \end{axis}
                \end{tikzpicture}}
        \end{center}
```

[image: This is what it looks like so far]

Answer (score 1):

`xlabel` is centered by default, and you can control the positioning of `ylabel` by setting `y label style={at={(axis description cs:0,1.05)},...}`. Similarly, the `xlabel` can be modified as you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\resizebox{10cm}{!}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    grid=major,
    xtick align = center,
    y label style={at={(axis description cs:0,1.05)},rotate=-90,anchor=south},
    xlabel={$t$},
    ylabel={$<i(t)>$},
    xmin=0,
    xmax=3,
    xtick={1,2,3},
    ymin=0,
    ymax=20,
    ytick={0,5,10,15,20}
    ]
    \addplot[thick,samples=400] {((1-2)*(x/1-1))^(1/(1-2))};
    \node at (axis cs:0.6,18) {$\kappa = 2$};
    \addplot[thick,samples=400] {((1-0.5)*(x/1+2))^(1/(1-0.5))};
    \node at (axis cs:2.6,7) {$\kappa = 0.5$};
    \addplot[thick,samples=400] {(exp(x/1+0))};
    \node at (axis cs:2.6,18) {$\kappa = 1$};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your answer!
This fixes the position of the y label.

However the x ticks are still misplaced for me even though I used the exact same code as you did.

How is this possible?

Comment: Okay now I figured it out. I needed to add the line "xticklabel style={anchor=north}"

somehow the anchor was set to west by default.

Thank you very much for your help.